# How to get a string instead of an array in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to do the following:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem c:\temp | Select-Object Name
foreach ($i in $files) {
    Write-Host "Filename is $i"
}
```

Sample result:

```
Filename is @{Name=oracle10204.rsp}
Filename is @{Name=powershell.txt}
```

How do I get only the following?

```
Filename is oracle10204.rsp
Filename is powershell.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer to get just the name from your example. Surround the $i with $( ) and reference the .Name property. The $() will cause it to evaluate the expression.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem c:\temp | Select-Object Name
foreach ($i in $files) {
    Write-Host "Filename is $($i.Name)"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With the -Name switch you can get object names only:

```
 Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Name
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are adamant about getting your original attempt to work, try replacing

```
Select-Object Name
```

with

```
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure why you are using `Select-Object` here, but I would just do:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp | % {Write-Host "Filename is $($_.name)"}
```

This pipes the output of Get-ChildItem to a Foreach-Object (abbreviation `%`), which runs the command for each object in the pipeline.

`$_` is the universal piped-object variable.

Comment: Thanks, your example works, but how to get my foreach statement to give correct result?

Comment: @jrara - I'm saying don't use your foreach statement since this is the same thing but a much more efficient way.  Pipelining is what powershell was designed for.

Comment: Well, yes, but I'm trying to learn powershell and I would like to know what is wrong with my foreach loop. I know that there is many other ways to do this.

Comment: In that case, remove the `Select-Object` and just output the name property of each file object.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this object as a string with the `Get-ChildItem -Name` parameter:

```
$variable = Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Name
```

This gives you a:

> System.String 
>   If you use the Name parameter, Get-ChildItem returns the object names as strings.

You can read about it in *[Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx)*.